# Classifying Singular Points as Regular/Irregular for Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, singularity, singularity-theory

The question asks to find the singular points of the Differential Equation and to classify each of them as regular/irregular:

$x(x^2+1)^2y''+y=0$

*Edit:* I gave it another shot and I ended up with 3 singular points:

$x=0$ (regular singular point)

$x=+i$ (irregular singular point)

$x=-i$ (irregular singular point)

Could you kindly let me know if I found the correct solution? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Singular points can be complex, so it's no problem.

Comment: @B.Goddard Can you please clarify? I found 2 singular points: x=0 as regular singular point and x=i as irregular singular point

Comment: You have $i$ and $-i$ as singular points.  They're both regular.

Comment: @B.Goddard Could you please include a detailed solution? Or possibly point me to a reference with an explanation? thanks